# Load configuration files dynamically using Spring

Tags: spring

We already have a setup in which we are loading files like :

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
             <value>file:${AN_ENV_CONFIGURED_DIR}/project.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
```

The config files are there in server in a separate location. I want to load the configuration files dynamically if there is a change in it. Now since I already have this setup is there a simple way to reload config files from Spring other than using `TimerTask` and if its the only way then still its not sufficing the need to loading the file immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, following is the code snippet.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basenames">
     <list>
       <value>file:${AN_ENV_CONFIGURED_DIR}/project.properties</value>
     </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

For more info : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html

Comment: Its a good choice but there are n number of services and I have to do for all the services for which we don't have access / cannot modify. Can we do at a container level ?

Comment: Here we are talking about making a properties file reloadable. The **n number of services** confused me. Can you please explain?

Comment: There are many services which has the type of configuration originally posted. Anyway i think i will ask each service member to update this in their config files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below bean to reload config.properties every 1 second.

```
@Component
public class PropertyLoader {

    @Autowired
    private StandardEnvironment environment;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
    public void reload() throws IOException {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        PropertySource<?> resourcePropertySource = propertySources.get("class path resource [config.properties]");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        propertySources.replace("class path resource [config.properties]", new PropertiesPropertySource("class path resource [config.properties]", properties));
    }
}
```

Your main config will look something like:

```
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:/config.properties")
public class HelloWorldConfig {
}
```

Then access the property any where:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

environment.get("my.property");
```